# How to change a Ubuntu One device name?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

In 12.04, how do I change the device name of Ubuntu One?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't. 
I think you can temporarily remove your device,  then add it again with the new name.

Comment: This is correct: there is no way to change the description associated with an OAuth token (what each item in this list represents) after it has been created.